# Get connected devices in WiFi access point (raspberry pi 3 & Windows IoT) c#

Tags: c#, uwp, wifi, raspberry-pi3, windows-iot-core-10

I am working in a project relating with raspberry pi 3 and windows iot. I have configured IoT on-boarding for changing it as access point. Now the access point works and i can connect with the internet through the access point.

Now i am in need of getting the connected devices from the raspberry pi 3 WiFi access point. I have tried all the mentioned tutorials and searched over every other links regarding this.

FYI, i tried manually arp -a command to get the connected devices in AP. It also works fine, but when i tried to run programmatically, it displays as "ACCESS DENIED ERROR 0x80070005"

I tried running through powershell using process launcher i get the same error. Also have given permission

```
HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\EmbeddedMode\ProcessLauncher /v AllowedExecutableFilesList /t REG_MULTI_SZ c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe\0
```

I also tried using SSH client the same error pops out. Any suggestion would be highly appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Device portal run the following command:

```
reg ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\EmbeddedMode\ProcessLauncher" /f /v AllowedExecutableFilesList /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe\0"
```

Like this:

[image]

Then get connected devices programmatically like this:

```
                    var result = await ProcessLauncher.RunToCompletionAsync(@"c:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe", "arp -a | findstr -i 192.168.137 | findstr /V 255 | findstr /V 192.168.137.1", options);
```

The result may be like this:
[image]

For a complete sample, you can reference [ExternalProcessLauncher](https://github.com/ms-iot/samples/tree/develop/ExternalProcessLauncher/CS).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The coding you provide works.   I have used "ProcessLauncher.RunToCompletionAsync" to get the ip address. By default it takes 10 seconds to run the query. Can i reduce the default query timing?

Answer (score 0):

I think this could be of help to you. At least when I read over it the last time it sounded like it would be able to list all conncted devices.

[Enumerate devices over a network](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/devices-sensors/enumerate-devices-over-a-network)